# OpenGL ES2.0 glTexImage2D() returns GL_INVALID_VALUE

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, texture2d

I have a problem trying to generate a texture (for a font atlas) on one of my Android devices (Samsung N5100 tablet). The below code works fine on iOS and on my Samsung S4.

glTextImage2D() keeps returning GL_INVALID_VALUE.

At first I thought it was a power of 2 issue but I've tried hardcoding various power of 2 values and it continues to fail. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE returns a value of 4096 but I can't even get 16x16 to work.

```
  glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
  glGenTextures( 1, &m_TextureAtlasStrip );
  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TextureAtlasStrip );
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
  glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );

  if( CheckGLError() )
    LogDebugf( "FAIL(9)" );

  GLint f = 0;
  glGetIntegerv( GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &f );
  LogDebugf( "GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: %d", f );

  if( CheckGLError() )
    LogDebugf( "FAIL(9F)" );

//nPow2RoundWidth = 2048;
//nPow2RoundWidth  = 1024;
//nPow2RoundWidth  = 512;
nPow2RoundWidth  = 16;
nPow2RoundHeight = 16;
LogDebugf( "nPow2RoundWidth: %d  nPow2RoundHeight: %d", nPow2RoundWidth, nPow2RoundHeight );

  glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, nPow2RoundWidth, nPow2RoundHeight, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );

  if( CheckGLError() )
  {
    LogDebugf( "AT FAIL(10)" );
    exit( 1 );
  }

  LogDebugf( "WORKED AT (10)" );
  exit( 1 );
```

What would cause this?

UPDATE:
If I change GL_RED to GL_RGB it works..

```
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, nPow2RoundWidth, nPow2RoundHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );
```

Comment: In openGL ES 2.0, GL_LUMINANCE  and GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA works fine. You can use the fetched values for whatever in your shader code. I tend to stick with the order GL_LUMINANCE (single value), GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA (two values), GL_RGB (three values) and GL_RGBA...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table 3.8 of the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf) defines the valid values for `internalformat` and `format` of `glTexImage2D`

They are, `GL_ALPHA`, `GL_LUMINANCE`, `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA`, `GL_RGB` and `GL_RGBA`.

Depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve, you will probably find `GL_LUMINANCE` or `GL_ALPHA` can be suitable substitutes.

Alternatively, [this extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_rg.txt) does support a red (and a red-green) texture, I think it's quite common, but isn't everywhere.

Comment: Thanks - GL_ALPHA should be the one. I used the below example (which uses GL_ALPHA also). Not sure why I had GL_RGB in there but that would have happened over a year ago.

https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_02